# Knockout Event on data bind update/add of view

Tags: knockout.js

i tried to search on web and knockout's documentation but could not find where and how.
**Is there  event when knockout has updated/added a data on your view?**

**i need to run some java script after the data has been updated/added by knockout.** i don't seem to find a built in event that is triggered when knockout is done doing data updates on the view.

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explicitly [subscribe](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly_subscribing_to_observables) to an observable:

```
myViewModel.personName.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    alert("The person's new name is " + newValue);
});
```

If you need to track changes for all of the observables, check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850020/knockoutjs-how-to-get-notications-for-all-the-properties-an-once).

To track array changes, check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149551/subscribe-to-observable-array-for-new-or-removed-entry-only).

Comment: how do i do this if its an array?