# How can i know change in knockout.js ViewModel just by change in its observable property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mvvm, knockout.js, viewmodel

I have a ViewModel in knockout.js for personal information.
I want javascript to think that whole PersonViewModel is changed if just a single observable property in that model is changed.

I also have another ViewModel for address and i want the same for it. 
As an end user of program I want program to tell which view model is changed by change in any of the observable property.

I could use "subscribe" but that means i would have to subscribe every observable inside the view model and i don't want to do that.
Figuratively, i want to subscribe the whole ViewModel instead of each observable inside it.
What should i do?

```
function PersonViewModel() {
        this.firstName = ko.observable("John");
        this.lastName = ko.observable("Doe");
        this.middleName = ko.observable();
        this.userName = ko.observable("Johnny");
        this.dateOfBirth = ko.observable("12/12/2012");

    this.firstName.subscribe(function () {
        alert("fisrtName changed");
    });
}

 function AddressViewModel() {
        this.city = ko.observable("@Model.City");
        this.street = ko.observable("@Model.Street");
    }

var pvm = new PersonViewModel();
var avm = new AddressViewModel();
var pNode = $("#personal-information").get(0);
var aNode = $("#address-information").get(0);
ko.applyBindings(pvm, pNode);
ko.applyBindings(avm, aNode);
```

My HTML:

```
  <div id="personal-information">
        <input data-bind="value: firstName" type="text" >
        <input data-bind="value: lastName" type="text" >
        <input data-bind="value: middleName" type="text" >
        <input data-bind="value: username" type="text" >
        <input data-bind="value: dateOfBirth" type="text" >
     </div>
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10622707/detecting-change-to-knockout-view-model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knockout includes a [`ko.toJS`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html) function that "clones your view model’s object graph, substituting for each observable the current value of that observable, so you get a plain copy that contains only your data and no Knockout-related artifacts." If you call `ko.toJS` in a computed, that computed will update whenever any observable in the view model is changed.

```
var p = ko.computed(function () {
    return ko.toJS(pvm);
});
var log = ko.observableArray();
p.subscribe(function (value) {
    log.push("Person changed");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mbest/ubLzwerp/

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/7850364/1287183

Comment: Thanks Michael. But now i've found that this work only with <input>, when i use a <select>(Dropdown) it will push a log, even on page load. Also, the content for my dropdown is supplied from mvc model containing list of selectListitems

Comment: The `value` binding for a `<select>` will update the observable to match one of the items in the list. That's why you get an update. You can initialize the "logger" after calling applyBindings for the main viewmodels or make sure the selected value is set correctly in the constructor.